# fixing problems in Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

when scaling window columns we fall out of the grid  anyone got any suggestions?
it seems that if the columns are not the same size happens to fall out of small-6

```
<div class="large-3 columns small-6 text-center"><img src="img/1.png" width="150" height="150">
  <h2> 1</h2>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis </p></div>
<div class="large-3 columns small-6 text-center">
<img src="img/2.png" width="150" height="150">
  <h2>2</h2>
  <h3> Lorem ipsum </h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet veniam, quis  </p></div>

<div class="large-3 columns small-6 text-center">
<img src="img/3.png" width="150" height="150">
<h2>3</h2>
  <h3>Is even more essential</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis </p></div>
<div class="large-3 columns small-6 text-center">
<img src="img/4.png" width="150" height="150">
 <h2>4</h2>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h3>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis </p></div>
</div>![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Please try to provide more information about the problem. What have you tried to fix that? A screenshot would be also handy in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you have a problem in the small screen. Maybe clearing float elements can help you. This clearing will show only for small screens

Try to add after two .columns element:

```
<div class="clearfix show-for-small"></div>

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; 
}

.clearfix:before, 
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; 
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both; 
}
```

Comment: um, the solution is that the columns are the same height, then float works as it should